# Automating web tasks?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, web-scraping, capybara

I play on chess.com and I'd like to download a history of my games.  Unfortunately, they don't make it easy: I can access 100 pages of 50 games one at a time, click "Select All" and "Download" and then they e-mail it to me.

Is there a way to write a script, in python or another language, that helps me automate any part of the process?  Something that simulates clicking a link?  Is Capybara useful for things like this outside of unit testing?  Selenium?

I don't have much experience with web development yet.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out CasperJS.  I use Python to fire CasperJS scripts to do web scraping and return data to Python to parse further or store to a database etc...

Python itself has BeautifulSoup and Mechanize but the combination is not great with Ajax based sites.

Python and CasperJS is perfect.

Comment: So, if the websites I'm looking at are not AJAX-based, BeautifulSoup might be the ideal solution?

Comment: yes I would say beautifulsoup is faster if you're not trying to grab dynamic data manipulated by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium could be a good candidate if you want to do something like this.

Here would be some pseudo code:

```
foreach page_link in page_links:
  page_link.click()
  select_all.click()
  download_link.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Helium](http://heliumhq.com/). It should be relatively easy to achieve what you need to do using this Python library:

```
start_chrome("chess.com")
...
click("Select All")
click("Download")
...
```

etc.